# Mover datos de un JComboBox a otro JComboBox

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox

Quiero hacer exactamente eso, tengo una lista y si selecciono un elemento en el `JComboBox a` se añade al `JComboBox b`, pasa que cuando se produce el add en el `JComboBox b` se lanza el evento y me devuelve el elemento al `JComboBox a`.

Aqui un MVCE para comprobarlo (si comentais el listener `B` veréis que funciona correctamente):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] lenguages = new String[] {"Java", "C++", "Pearl", "Python", "Bash", "Basic", "Cobol", "Haskell", ".NET", "Pascal"};

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    final JComboBox<String> comboA = new JComboBox<String>(lenguages);
    final JComboBox<String> comboB = new JComboBox<String>();
    comboA.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(210, 30));
    comboB.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(210, 30));

    comboA.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // recuperamos el elemento seleccionado y  lo pasamos al otro combo 
            String elementoSeleccionado = (String) comboA.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("A>" + elementoSeleccionado);

            // lo pasamos al otro combo
            comboB.addItem(elementoSeleccionado);

            // y lo eliminamos
            comboA.removeItem(elementoSeleccionado);
        }
    });

    comboB.addActionListener (new ActionListener () {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // recuperamos el elemento seleccionado y  lo pasamos al otro combo 
            String elementoSeleccionado = (String) comboB.getSelectedItem();
            System.out.println("B>" + elementoSeleccionado);

            // lo pasamos al otro combo
            comboA.addItem(elementoSeleccionado);

            // y lo eliminamos
            comboB.removeItem(elementoSeleccionado);
        }
    });

    // contenedor para los jcombobox
    panel.add(comboA);
    panel.add(comboB);

    // frame principal
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
    frame.setSize(500, 100);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

RESULTADO (siempre combo B vacio)

```
A>Cobol
B>Cobol
A>Cobol
B>Cobol
A>Bash
B>Bash
A>.NET
B>.NET
```

Answer (score -1):

Creo entender lo que quieres hacer, hice algo similar con ayuda de esto
http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.phptitle=JComboBox_dependiente_de_otro_JComboBox

Saludos!!

Comment: aparte que se desaconsejan los links sin incluir las partes más importantes, el link no es correcto: *La página no está. Quizás puedas encontrarla buscando con google por este sitio*.....